# SQL: Order by statement with start value

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a field like this:

- 1月~3月
- 12月~1月
- 3月~12月
- 4月~12月
- 9月~8月
- 6月~7月

How can i sort that column following:

- 4月~12月
- 6月~7月
- 9月~8月
- 12月~1月
- 1月~3月
- 3月~12月

It start by 4 and end by 3 (4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-1-2-3)(month)

Comment: Why is 4 (april) lower than 3 (march)? Side-note: If it contains such a logic i would create an (extra) `smallint` column.

Comment: Cause that is case of financial year. Financial year start:01/04  - end: 31/03 in one year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it, you need to separate out the numeric portion of your field, and also use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CAST(LEFT(Col1, CHARINDEX('月',Col1)-1)AS INT) >= 4  THEN 1 END DESC
        ,CAST(LEFT(Col1, CHARINDEX('月',Col1)-1)AS INT)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a279/11/0)

SQL Server syntax above, might vary depending on database.

Answer (score 0):

```
 order by case when col < 4 then 1 else 0 end, col
```

or if it's really a varchar

```
 order by case when convert(int,substring(col,1,1)) < 4 then 1 else 0 end, col
```